# Issues with compiling a C++ program taking in a file

Tags: c++

I'm having some problems with compiling for some reason and I'm trying to figure out the exact reason on why its happening:

```
g++ Assignment1.cpp test.txt
 warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
         printf(op); // To test whether what's scan is what needs to be scanned.
                  ^
/usr/bin/ld:test.txt: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:test.txt:1: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here's the program itself:

```
string op;
    char output;
    int i,trig[6];
    FILE *file_ptr;
    file_ptr = fopen(argv[1],"r+");
    if (file_ptr != NULL){
        fscanf(file_ptr,"%1s (%d,%d) (%d,%d) (%d,%d)", &output, &trig[1], &trig[2],&trig[3],&trig[4],&trig[5],&trig[6]);
        char *op = &output;
        printf(op); // To test whether what's scan is what needs to be scanned.
    }
    else {
        printf("File Not Found!");
    }

    fclose(file_ptr);
return 0;
}
```

and the test.txt file is simply: T(30,20) (34, 30) (12, 25)

Comment: What if you try `g++ Assignment1.cpp`  and then run the resulting programme with test.txt as argument ?

Comment: What are you doing trying to _link_ a text file into your program??

Comment: BTW your `printf` usage is wrong. Why did you ignore the warning?

Comment: That way one can write up a list of coordinates in a text file and thus the program I'm writing up can scan it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also open file like this
i have remover string op because you have declared char *op with the same name

```
   file_ptr=fopen("test.txt","r");
```

//your code should look something like this now

```
  int main(){

//string op;

char output;
int i,trig[6];
FILE *file_ptr;
file_ptr = fopen("test.txt","r");
if (file_ptr != NULL){
    fscanf(file_ptr,"%1s (%d,%d) (%d,%d) (%d,%d)", &output, &trig[1], &trig[2],&trig[3],&trig[4],&trig[5],&trig[6]);
    char *op = &output;
    printf(op); // To test whether what's scan is what needs to be scanned.
}
else {
    printf("File Not Found!");
}

fclose(file_ptr);
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: While I'd accept the idea, I kinda was hoping for a way so I can put it in through the command line. Is that just not possible?

Comment: Yes, like g++ assignment1.cpp test.txt That's how I want the file to be sent into the program. Is that just not possible to mix in with scanf? That's what I really wanna do with this program.